# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0:35:00'

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, normalization, scaling

The below code is not working I am trying to convert (Time Series Data) in (Time) column on my CSV file contain only one column that what I need to convert it or Normalizing it:

```
# Normalize time series data
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# load the dataset and print the first 5 rows
series = read_csv("E:\Dataset\Copy3.csv", header=0)
print(series.head())
# prepare data for normalization
values = series.values
values = values.reshape((len(values), 1))
# train the normalization
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(values)
print('Min: %f, Max: %f' % (scaler.data_min_, scaler.data_max_))
# normalize the dataset and print the first 5 rows
normalized = scaler.transform(values)
for i in range(5):
 print(normalized[i])
# inverse transform and print the first 5 rows
inversed = scaler.inverse_transform(normalized)
for i in range(5):
 print(inversed[i])

Output:
         Time
     0  0:35:00
     1  0:55:00
     2  0:59:00
     3  2:11:00
     4  2:45:00
```

I get this error: 
[Press here to show Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIIan.png)
        ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0:35:00'

I wish to get some help, thanks for all

Comment: which line makes problem ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: string `"0:35:00"` is not float value so what do you try to do?  Maybe you should convert it to `datetime` object and later get total seconds.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I will edit it now.

Comment: you are assigning scaler = scaler.fit(values) , and than you are using this to do inverse transform , which is why you are getting error ..

Comment: I want to scale the real-time in range (0-1), something like (0:35:00) to 0.551242

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you get the pandas dtype of type column? It is of type datetime? 
Try `series['Time']` to find out.

If it returns type object then you need to use the `parse_dates=` parameter in the `read_csv` function.

Also you could try to parse the column manually by:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strftime(series['time'], '%H:%M:%S')
```

which will convert the string into datetime object for you to use.

Comment: I get this error:  TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Series'

Answer (score 0):

If u want to transform an intr-day time into digit, as there are 86400 seconds in a day, you can scale the time into a range of (0,86399).

```
from datetime import datetime
def intraday_time_scaler(t):
    tmp_time = datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M:%S')
    return tmp_time.hour*3600 + tmp_time.minute*60 + tmp_time.second

df['time_scaled'] = df.apply(lambda row: intraday_time_scaler(row['Time']),axis=1)
```

Alternatively if your range of time '00:00:00' exceeds '23:59:59', eg:
'35:43:33', do something like:

```
time_list = '35:43:33'.split(':')
time_numeric = int(time_list[0])*3600 + int(time_list[1])*60 + int(time_list[2])
```

Comment: Thanks allot, that means I should calculate the total time by the second firstly, then scale the total time by a second

Comment: counting number of second is a linear way to scale your time input if you want to use time as a factor for machine learning. From there you can try to apply various means of weighting /kernel functions depending on your purpose.